# Problem Appending multiple Excel Files to Access Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have 163 Excel files in a folder that are all formatted the same.  I want to combine them all into a single table in Access.  I set up a table that matches the format, then created a module with the following code. I copied this code from a post I found on the web that was marked as "the answer".  I changed the 1) address for mypath, 2) the extention from "*.xls" to "*.xlsx", and 3) the file type and table name in the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet statement, but everything else is unchanged.

When I run it, I get Compile Error:  Wend without While.  I see the While in the statement, so I don't understand why I get this error.

```
Option Compare Database

Function Impo_allExcel()

Dim myfile
Dim mypath


mypath = "C:\Users\bbnewman\Desktop\Temp\temp\"
ChDir (mypath)

myfile = Dir()
Do While myfile <> ""
  If myfile Like "*.xlsx" Then
     'this will import ALL the excel files
     '(one at a time, but automatically) in this folder.
     ' Make sure that's what you want.
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "LCRHistory", mypath & myfile
  End If
  myfile = Dir()
Wend

End Function
```

Comment: The loop is a `Do... Loop`, so the terminator is `Loop`. Here is a [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement) providing more context.

Comment: Or: `While ... Wend`.

Comment: I tried changing Wend to Loop.  I also changed tried deleting the "Do", leaving While==>Wend.  In both cases, I now get "Run Time Error 9:   Invalid Procedure or Argument" at Line 12 "myfile = Dir()".  How am I using that incorrectly?

Comment: You have to give `Dir()` something the first time you call it.  How about this? `myfile = Dir(mypath & "*.xlsx")`  Then you wouldn't need the `If myfile Like "*.xlsx" Then` test later because you would only be dealing with XLSX file names.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm in business!